# How to change the License page default header "License Agreement" in Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup

I want to change the default header "License Agreement" in the license page in Inno Setup.

I am unable to find anything to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Handling and customizing errors and messages in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65980371/850848).

This particular message is defined by the `WizardLicense` message.

You can change it in the [`[Messages]` section](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=messagessection):

```
[Messages]
WizardLicense=Privacy policy
```